# Evaluate a limit by using squeeze theorem

Tags: limits

We're supposed to use the Squeeze Theorem to prove that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {1-\cos x\over x^2} = \frac12$$

I tried this:

$$-1\le \cos x \le 1$$ 
$$-1\le -\cos x \le 1$$
$$0\le 1-\cos x \le 2$$
$$0\le {1-\cos x\over x^2} \le {2\over x^2}$$

Then using limits we have:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}0\le \lim_{x\to 0} {1-\cos x\over x^2} \le \lim_{x\to 0}{2\over x^2}$$

And for obvious reasons the first limit is $\Bbb {0}$, and the third limit is $\Bbb \infty$

What do I do now? Or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't squeeze hard enough, i.e. your bounds $-1$ and $1$ are too trivial (or at least $-1$ is). You need something that gets "tight" when $x\to 0$.

Comment: Even if I took another bound in the left, I still have infinity as a result of the limit in the right.

Comment: The $\infty$ on the right is a consequence of using merely $-1\le\cos x$ (though this got turned to $-\cos x\le 1$ inbetween). You need som estimate $f(x)\le \cos x$ with the property that $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to 0$. Hint: make use of $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x = 1$.

Comment: So you're suggesting I could take two different bounds starting off $\cos x$? Or should I start off from something else, because I've tried already to change bounds but it will lead me to $0$ in one side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bounds do not seem tight enough. If you know how to squeeze $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ then one possible solution would be to reduce your limit into $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$ and to squeeze that.

Comment: As in multiplying by $1+\cos x \over {1+\cos x}$ ?

Comment: That should work, yes.

Comment: I split it into two limits, the one you suggested and $1\over {1+\cos x}$. Can I evaluate the second one before using the Squeeze Theorem?

Comment: In practice it wouldn't make a difference if you evaluated it right now. To be perfectly formal, I would probably wait until the end step when you take $x$ to $0$ for the squeeze.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (which I think I am) but then I would have to evaluate $(-1\le {{\sin x}^2 \over {x^2}} \le 1)\times (-1\le \cos x \le 1)$ The second one until I get to $1\over {1+\cos x}$ so I can squeeze both?

Comment: The problem of squeezing the function $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ is very well known. The only squeeze based solution that I'm aware of will rely on geometric methods. How are you multiplying a set of inequalities?

Comment: No, the problem is not squeezing $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$, I've done it already, my question was that if it's OK to split them the way I did, and then squeeze both parts separately.

Comment: $1+cosx$ simply goes to $2$. There's no squeezing involved...

Comment: Look I have this then:

$\lim_{x\to 0} {\sin x^2\over x^2} \times \lim_{x\to 0} {1 \over {1+\cos x}}$ 
Then: $\frac12 \times \lim_{x\to 0} {\sin x^2\over x^2}$ and then I just do the Squeeze Theorem like this: $\frac12 \times (-1\le {{\sin x}^2 \over {x^2}} \le 1)$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that seems fine. Just a note, the \frac{sin^2(x)}{x^2} is squeezed to $1$. All you wrote is an inequality, not a squeeze. Assuming you've done the squeeze properly (which you did not write), then it's fine.

Comment: Oh yes I know, I was just asking if that's the previous step before I use the squeeze theorem in that inequality.

Answer (score 2):

This might be an overkill, but according to the Taylor theorem, for any nonzero $x$ you can find $\xi_x$ between zero and $x$ in such a way that
$$
  \cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{1}{4!} \cos(\xi_x) \cdot x^4.
$$
Thus, shuffling those terms around, you would get
$$
  \frac{1}{2} - \frac{x^2}{4!} \leq  \frac{1 - \cos x}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{x^2}{4!} \cos(\xi_x) \leq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x^2}{4!}, \quad x \neq 0.
$$
Obviously
$$
  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{x^2}{4!} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
and you are done.